# Rollback of queries in underlying methods not happening on RuntimeException thrown from calling method which is annotated @Transactional

Tags: java, spring-boot, rollback, transactional

This is the API endpoint method -

```
@Path("endpoint")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional
    public List<UserTransaction> cashoutWithFee(@BeanParam XAmount amount, @FormParam("to") String to,
            @FormParam("account") String account) Boolean consent, @Context SecurityContext security)
                    throws NetCardException {

..  Some logic here..

UserTransaction feeTx = session.as(user).withdrawalFee(feeAmount,amount.asAmount());

                List<UserTransaction> myList = new ArrayList<UserTransaction>();
                myList.add(feeTx);

                if(feeTx.getStatus() == TransactionStatus.SUCCESSFUL)
                {

UserTransaction utx = session.as(user).withdrawOwnBank(amount.asAmount(), to,
                            account == null ? null : account.trim(),
                            ifsc == null ? null : ifsc.trim());

                    myList.add(utx);

                    String parentTxnId = utx.getId();

throw new RuntimeException("simulating withdrawal failure");
..  Some more logic here..
}
```

The `withdrawalFee()` method in another class calls some other methods and so on. It does some db insert query at some point.

The `withdrawOwnBank()` method similarly does some db insert and some external API call.

Even though the runtime exception (hardcoded here) happens, I do not see the inserted queries getting removed. Any pointers to what am I missing? I am new to the transactional feature of Spring Boot.

Comment: Try `@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)`

Comment: It should rollback with RunTimeException. Can you enable debug and verify if Transactional annotation is processed by container and a transaction is started using the same(should appear in logs).

Comment: Something like:
`    o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
    o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@14f3efe7] for JPA transaction
    o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [com.example.demo.Controller]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''`

Comment: @Puneet I don't see any of those. In debug mode, I can see this info - `2018-10-25 15:10:28,251 18440 [main] INFO  [PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:325] - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$178d9bdc] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)`

Comment: seems like startup log, you should check transaction log. When you are calling controller's service.

Comment: @SandeepanNath the method's you mentioned - `withdrawalFee()` and `withdrawOwnBank()` how are they annotated? Do these methods have same transaction propagation or new? Similar to the log that you posted 2 comments before, check what type of propagation happens inside these each method. That would give you the clue. Please post the method structure to help further.

Comment: @SandeepanNath Please provide the code for session on which you are calling withdrawOwnBank and withdrawalFee methods, if this a service calling in some repository, that repository should be @@Transactional.